# CFNetwork memory spike when fetching image

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cfnetwork

I'm profiling my app in Instruments, and have found a troubling amount of allocations by CFNetwork when I use AFNetworking to fetch a remote image.

In one instance I saw 89 MB of allocations (the image is only around 200 KB in size). I've attached a screenshot to demonstrate. Has anyone else noticed this before? The memory is released appropriately but I can't understand why this happens in the first place.

[image: Profile]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should add that I am only viewing "All Heap Allocations", not "All Heap & Anonymous VM"

Comment: Did you find any workaround or any chance to fix this memory increment? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: No @Rudeboy, just ended up tolerating it.

Comment: just check it on iOS 8.3, seems to be fixed.

Comment: You're right, seems like this has been fixed. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing the same issue on iOS 8 ONLY. It doesn't happen on any version of iOS 7.  On simulator its 132kb, on a device its 144kb.

It seem's to be related to this issue:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2314

I'm performing a http get using nsurlsession in this example. If you hit a place that doesn't send keep-alive, ie google.com, it wont malloc those kb. But if you hit a place that sends keep-alive, it will.

```
NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%.20f", @"http://someplace.com/?test=", (double)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:nil] resume];
```

[image: instruments]