# HTTPNetStreamInfo::_readStreamClientCallBack(__CFReadStream*, unsigned long) increases memory allocation

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, xamarin, httpclient

I am trying to download large video file with httpClient post method. I am working Xamarin.iOS, but it seems to be issue of iOS (NSURLConnection/session) as the Xamarin codes convert it into native one.

My device is having IOS8.1. A memory is kept increasing when I try to download that video file up to 300MB. It goes down when its getting completed (if it gets completed before crashing).  It crashes most of the time. I am attaching screenshots for the reference.

I found many people having this issue, but no one have the solution, like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458954/cfnetwork-memory-spike-when-fetching-image/30527819#30527819). Did somebody get a chance to fix this issue?

Please let me know if you need more input to understand the issue

[image]

[image]

Comment: and yeah, I have tried : -  NSUrlCache sharedCache = new ECache ();
            sharedCache.DiskCapacity = 0;
            sharedCache.MemoryCapacity = 0;

            NSUrlCache.SharedCache = sharedCache; its not working on iOS 8.0

Comment: NSUrlCache sharedCache = new NSUrlCache ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange but yes, it is fixed in iOS8.3. NSURLCache was broken in iOS 8.x till iOS8.3. So it was not able to clear the cache. But as I have updated it to iOS8.3, it came down to 32KB block and consumes max 5-7MB.